# ActiveRecord many_to_many with custom table and column name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to map in Sinatra with ActiveRecord my MySQL dB. 
The db doesn't follow the ActiveRecord convention, so I need to map everything adding attributes to my Classes.

Everything is ok with one to many and one to one association, but I have problems with m to m.

I have an article table named "Eve_Articles"

I have a product tablet named "Eve_product"

I have a join table named "Eve_Articles_Product" where tree_id is the article ID and prod_id is the Product ID.

I create the models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  has_one :image, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: 'tree_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, 

end

class Product< ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles, 
end
```

But I don't know how to define the custom join table with custom keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join_table` option. Also you will have to set the `table_name` for `Article` and `Product` since its not following the rails convention

You will have to set the table name after the habtm call according to this line from documentation.

> WARNING: If you’re overwriting the table name of either class, the
>   table_name method MUST be declared underneath any
>   has_and_belongs_to_many declaration in order to work.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  has_one :image, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: 'tree_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => "Eve_Articles_Product", :association_foreign_key => 'tree_id', :foreign_key => 'prod_id'
  self.table_name = "Eve_Products"
end

class Product< ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles, :join_table => "Eve_Articles_Product", :association_foreign_key => "prod_id", :foreign_key => 'tree_id'
  self.table_name = "Eve_Articles"
end
```